# Oracle - Select For Update with commit - Inside Loop [PerformanceTuining]

Tags: oracle

I have PLSQL code which process million transactions a day.

```
DECLARE
    Cursor C1 is select * from myTable WHERE status='UNPROCESSED';
    Type table_type is table of c1%rowtype;
    l_record table_type;
    l_limit number := 5000;
    resource_busy EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (resource_busy, -54);
BEGIN
    OPEN cursor c1;
    LOOP
       FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO l_record LIMIT l_limit;
          IF l_record.count > 0 THEN
             FOR l_idx IN 1 .. l_record.COUNT LOOP
                 BEGIN
                   SELECT * FROM myTable
                     where primary_key = l_record(l_idx).primary_key
                   FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;

                   --do the processing 
                   COMMIT;
                EXCEPTION
                   WHEN resource_busy THEN
                        --SKIP TO NEXT RECORD.. RECORD IS BEING PROCESSED BY OTHER JOB    
                   WHEN OTHERS THEN
                         --LOG ERROR AND SKIP TO NEXT RECORD.. 
             END LOOP;
          END IF; 
       EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND; 
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I have a function similar to above plsql anonymous block. That function is called by job every x Minutes.
Job1 -- Pick all the record and do processing and mark status as PROCESSED.
Job2 executes after x minutes -- It may pick the record which is already picked by JOB1 and is not yet processed. Thats why I have SELECT FOR UPDATE NO WAIT.

My Question is that, is there any way I can make this code still better wherein
1) I can avoid processing a record which is being processed by another job.
2) I need to commit as soon as processing is over(its a payment processing system,so that money is availble to the end user immediately.

Thanks a lot in  advance for  your help

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for in question 2.  You want to commit immediately, you have a commit inside the loop already.  Depending on how expensive the processing is, I wouldn't be surprised if the vast majority of time is already being spent waiting on commits.  So I'm not sure what you're trying to improve.  Of course, not committing for every row will improve performance and cause many users to see their transactions process sooner.  It's better for the person that happens to be the first row in the first batch to have frequent commits, it's much worse for those in the last batch.

Comment: I am looking to improve the above code. Is there any other better way to write the above code so that If multiple jobs should not pick the same record for processing. Ex. Job 1 and Job 2 picks same 10 record. The code should make sure both of them are not processing same record.The above code works fine, but I am looking for something better.

Comment: Have you considered use oracle's queues?. First process loads i/record to queue. Other jobs dequeue this messages and make calculation on them.

Comment: We are not using queue. We are using  Autosys  to schedule jobs. Because the volume of transaction is high, we created 15 parallel jobs, so that records can be processed fast. Suppose we have 15  records in table, so if we process sequentially, it will take 15sec(assuming each job takes 1s). But since 15 jobs are running it will take (1sec approx). Now there are possibility that the jobs pic the same record for processing, thats why I have added select for update nowait..  I am looking an alternative to avoid this select inside the loop....